# Is it healthy to continually call on resources(R) in Android?

Tags: android, performance

I have an application that requires data from a list in more than one classes extending `Context`. Sometimes I can pass the reference of the list to these classes and sometimes I cannot. So, I was wondering if putting the list to `R.array.mylist` and then continually calling from them in different classes might be a better idea? I specifically want to know if there is "high/low/acceptable"(in terms of memory & CPU) overhead to calling Resources continually.

Any suggestions/answers is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the content of R.array.mylist ? Is the content always constant across the application life time ?

Comment: yes. But very rarely is changed at the initialization time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "R" (resources) file is a static reference to XML defined objects. Creating a reference in XML allows you to reference those objects using objects that extend `Context`. It uses the `Resources` class to reference these objects.

If you inspect the source code (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/content/res/Resources.java#Resources) you will see it is essentially a handler for these XML defined classes. If you have access to `Context` then there are few steps you can take to improve upon a the short reference path that `Context` and `Resources` provide.

You can build your own mechanism for storing and/or referencing this array or you can use the one provided for you by the framework. Most likely you will find that the framework offers acceptable performance in terms of speed, memory allocation, etc. Since `Context` and `Resources` are loaded with your `Application` object, there is little overhead involved in using these tools. You will notice the source code attempts to optimize caching of XML objects, etc. That means the accessing and caching mechanism may not be optimized for some use-cases.

You may have situations where you can beat the effectiveness of the framework, but for most situations it is just fine. If you have a special use-case (like an array of 100,000 elements) then you might be able to optimize better than the framework. Most likely you will find that it is both convenient and effective to store your `array` as an XML defined object.